# "No Bake" Riddle

Tags: riddle, wordplay, language, regional-dialects

- I'm quick, I'm easy
- You can make me in a jiffy
- I'm on a farm
- I'm in your kitchen
- I'm in the pasture
- I lay, I rot, in more places then one
- I'm smelly, but I'm also very tasty
- I have nicknames but I prefer one
- What am I?

**Note-** *You may not recognize the nickname*

**Hint- Nice title, hey?**

Comment: Re the tags, I've opened a discussion here: http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/3266/ (here be spoilers!)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've been steaming over this for a bit now, and I can come up with nothing other than:

> A Cow pie; that being the pile of dung left by a cow, as well as a chocolately sweet (I'm familiar with the packaged candy from Baraboo, WI, but it also appears that there are "no-bake" cow pie/pile/patty recipes which popped after just searching those name variants).

I'm quick, I'm easy

> No bake recipes are often less time consuming and involved, since no cooking is needed.  It goes without saying that it's very easy for cows to make their pies.

You can make me in a jiffy

> Again, with no time in the oven, those patties would be done in the time it takes them to set.

I'm on a farm
I'm in your kitchen
I'm in the pasture

> Cows are on farms and roam the pastures, so this is where they leave their pies (Definitely Wisconsin...).  And the kitchen is where you would make the confectionery variety.

I lay, I rot, in more places than one

> Fields can be littered with pies.

I'm smelly, but I'm also very tasty

> The cow's version is smelly, the chocolate is tasty.

I have nicknames but I prefer one

> The origin is cow dung, but the cows' presentation of the dung likens it to a pie, a patty, or a pile (plus cow chips), which lead to us humans wanting chocolate in the same appetizing aesthetic.  Lots of nicknames, but I think cow pie is most common.

What am I?

> A cow pie/patty/pile/chip etc., of which the edible variety is a no bake treat, as the title hints.  (The cow variety could be baked by the sun and then burned by settlers, but that's neither here nor there)

Comment: You got it, good job

Comment: @Blake Thanks, and great riddle.  It makes me hungry, so I'm glad I can enjoy a cow pie without having to plan a trip to the Dells.

Comment: @raisinghellyer I googled cow pie and gives me something that WON'T makes me hungry... or there are different meanings?

Comment: @Alex Yes, there are different meanings.  If you just google cow pie, you'll see actual cow dung pies, but still should be able to see a link to the Baraboo candy I referenced in my answer (but maybe I get that result due to my proximity to Wisconsin).  If you add "chocolate" to your search, you will see the other definition.  Or look up the name variants, like cow pile; the first link is for no bake cookies, which is how I knew I was on the right path.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are talking about

> a cheese

- I'm quick, I'm easy

> No idea for this one.

- You can make me in a jiffy

> Cheese can be handmade.

- I'm on a farm
- I'm in your kitchen
- I'm in the pasture

> Cheese can be found on a farm (cheese production), in a kitchen (on a cheese plate) and in the pasture (goat milk that is used for cheese).

- I lay, I rot, in more places then one
- I'm smelly, but I'm also very tasty

> Some cheese smells a lot and they .. "extend" with age (they overflow). The more they smell, the tastier they are.

- I have nicknames but I prefer one

> They are many varieties of cheese. They can be called by their specific name ... or by the classic "cheese".

Comment: "Note- You may not recognize the nickname". I doubt 'cheese' would be that nickname, because most English speakers would have heard of the word 'cheese'.

Comment: We may not recognize that nickname because they is no "cheese" member on puzzling stack exchange :D

Comment: That's a good guess but not quite

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> Cornbread

I'm quick, I'm easy

> It really doesn't take much time to throw together cornbread

You can make me in a jiffy

> [Jiffy mix](https://www.jiffymix.com/)

I'm on a farm

> Corn comes from farms and cornbread is considered a farm staple

I'm in your kitchen

> It's food, where else would you find it?

I'm in the pasture

> Cornbread (or it's early descendants) was often taken by shepherds into a pasture as food. Also, this could be a play on the fields where corn is grown?

I lay, I rot, in more places then one

> Corn and cornbread can be found all over the world

I'm smelly, but I'm also very tasty

> No one says smells have to be bad :P

I have nicknames but I prefer one

> There are many names for cornbread: cornbread, johnny cakes, corncakes, hushpuppies, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are referring to:

> Bacteria

- I'm quick, I'm easy
- You can make me in a jiffy

  > Bacteria reproduce quickly and easily
- I'm on a farm
- I'm in the pasture
- I'm in your kitchen

  > Yep.
- I lay, I rot, in more places then one

  > Bacteria is pretty much everywhere.
- I'm smelly, but I'm also very tasty

  > Blue Cheese anyone?
- I have nicknames but I prefer one

  > Germ is a nickname, but it is pretty recognizable.

Comment: That's actually a pretty good guess but nope

Answer (score 0):

Are you:

> An Egg?

I'm quick, I'm easy
You can make me in a jiffy

> Easy to prepare (sunny side anyone?)

I'm on a farm

> Yup

I'm in your kitchen

> Yup..

I'm in the pasture

> Yup...

I lay, I rot, in more places then one

> Some eggs are igonred after getting 'laid'

I'm smelly, but I'm also very tasty

> Egg doesn't smell good, but it taste great!

I have nicknames but I prefer one

> I dunno about this one...(EDIT: hm..cackleberries? roonies?)

What am I?

> egg

Also,

> OP does not like cakes? (baked with egg as an ingridient)

Comment: That nickname one is really important, keep trying though